# Will I need media queries when I already set the width=device-width in my meta element?

Tags: css, responsive

a newbie question:

Let's say, I am writing a basic HTML template, nothing fancy. I am placing "width=device-width" in my meta element.

Will I still need to add media queries later along the process to ensure that my template is responsive or is having the "width=device-width" taken care of that already for me?

Comment: You might. It depends on the template and what responsive behaviour you want from it.

Answer (score 2):

When the first iPhone came out, web pages were all designed for desktop screens. The iPhone had a tiny screen in comparison.

To compensate for this, the iPhone pretended to have a much wider screen and just zoomed everything out. Then the user could zoom in on the bit of the page they wanted to look at.

This means that your page designed for a desktop sized window could work on the phone.

But Apple wanted people to be able to design pages that actually work on a narrow screen, so they introduced meta viewport.

By saying `width=device-width` you turn off the emulation of a large screen and the browser renders for the actual screen size.

Now consider the desktop version of a popular website:

[image: Desktop eBay]

And the mobile version:

[image: Mobile eBay]

While they share a lot of the same design principles, they have differences.

Designs for phone sized screens can't take advantage of the space provided by desktop sized screens.

Designs for desktop sized screens often won't fit on a phone screen.

That's why you need media queries. (You can creat designs which work on a wide variety of screen sizes, but they generally aren't optimal).

If you **didn't** use `width=device-width` the you wouldn't need a media query … but the phone experience would be awful as the user would have to zoom in and out.